# What is this purple flowering plant?

Tags: identification

What is this plant, is it a weed, and is it poisonous?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It's leaves are too broad to be the Canadian thistle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a species of wild Ageratum, a genus of plants in the family Asteraceae. It might be Ageratum houstonianum or Ageratum conyzoides which are commonly called "billygoat weed". There are several species in the genus. The Wikipedia link mentions both "weed" and "toxicity" in their article about the genus Ageratum, but some species are grown for their flowers. I hope the following links are helpful.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ageratum

http://wallumsmusings.blogspot.com/2012/07/ageratum-blue-billy-goat-weed.html

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ageratum_conyzoides

https://www.flickr.com/photos/31031835@N08/15596972833

Comment: Thanks for the input :) Masterful suggestion.

Comment: Yes, upon closer inspection u r right. Amazing ! According to my government database we have both Ageratum houstonianum Mill., and conyzoides L.. Both non-native invaders. Thanks ! And according to their database A. houstonianum flowers year round ! Fantastic !